# Error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10,10' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I have a table that lists all employees in the database but when I deleted all of them using `$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM $this->emp_tbl");`

I got this error:

> Sucessfully deleted!Database Failed: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '-10,10' at line 1

As a test to see if the error will disappear, I tried adding a record via phpmyadmin instead & indeed this error disappears & it will now display 1 record.. How will I fix this error & still displays a "blank table instead" if no record is found?

Comment: Probably a case of not escaping characters

Comment: no.. i think it's because in displaying the table, there are values needed but there are no data anymore to be displayed so i guess that's causing the error.. e.g. :  <td> <input type="checkbox"  name="myname[]" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" > </td>  but there's no more record ... not sure.. h

Comment: try to `die("DELETE FROM $this->emp_tbl");` before running a query, you will see the exact query output and then you can show us what's wrong. Also, you are not showing us the full query (-10,10 is missing in your code sample)

Comment: `echo "DELETE FROM $this->emp_tbl"` to see what you're actually trying to execute!

Comment: i'm able to delete all the records.. it was successful but since the page automatically loads what is left after deletion, it will now give me an error since $this->result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $this->emp_tbl", $this->connection);  OR maybe this: <td> <input type="checkbox"  name="myname[]" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" > </td> is just giving null.. no problem with deleting but seems error is for displaying what's left in the database since there's none left & the table displayed requires those values that are queried from database.. so how can i just DISPLAY A BLANK TABLE??

Answer (score 0):

Try this... object variable might not be parsing

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM {$this->emp_tbl}");
```

Otherwise why can't you use `Truncate` command?

```
mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE {$this->emp_tbl}");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. I can't find any info about this case in official documentation but try:

- don't use '-' in your queries ( for values and table names )
- use PDO.